# Can I decode this audio format?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm writing a Python program which depends on FFMPEG to decode audio into WAV format. I'd like to be able to process as many types of audio, but I need a way to quickly check if I can actually work with the uploaded file or not. I've compiled my own FFMPEG installation here.

Specifically, I'd like to enforce logic like this in my application:

```
if ffmpeg_type(file_path) is not "audio":
    raise Exception("Bro, that's not an audio file.")
elif not ffmpeg_can_decode_audio(file_path):
    raise Exception("I have no way of working with this.")
```

(I realize that it wouldn't be as easy as just calling these methods, I assume I'd need to parse output from a system call.)

Is there a way that I could use the command-line `ffmpeg`, `ffprobe`, etc. to determine if a given file is an audio file and if I can decode it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FFProbe to identify the file type, but you'll most likely need to maintain a database of file formats you know how to handle within your application. However, here's a quick snippet:

```
import json, subprocess
file_name = u'/path/to/some/file.mp3'
command=["/path/to/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe",
         '-print_format', 'json',
         '-v', 'quiet',
         '-show_error',
         '-show_format',
         #'-show_frames',
         #'-show_packets',
         '-show_streams',
         '-show_program_version',
         '-show_library_versions',
         '-show_versions',
         '-show_private_data',
         file_name]
process_data=subprocess.Popen(command, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
returncode = process_data.wait()
json_result=json.loads(process_data.stdout.read())
print json_result.get(u'format')
```

This function will return a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
"format": {
    "filename": "/path/to/some/file.mp3",
    "nb_streams": 1,
    "format_name": "mp3",
    "format_long_name": "MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)",
    "start_time": "0.000000",
    "duration": "12.416125",
    "size": "198658",
    "bit_rate": "128000",
    "tags": {
        "title": "Test of MP3 File              ",
        "artist": "Me                            ",
        "album": "Me                            ",
        "date": "2006",
        "comment": "test                        ",
        "track": "1",
        "genre": "Other"
    }
```

From this dictionary, you can extract the 'format' of the file, knowing only the path to that file! Hope this helps.

Comment: Many times, I don't even know the type of the file after it's been received, I don't have an extension for it.

Comment: Can I assume that if FFMPEG has no idea what kind of file it is, then `ffprobe` will fail when trying to analyze the file?

Comment: If it doesn't know what type of file it is, then yes. However, ffprobe even identifies .txt files as `u'format_long_name': u'Tele-typewriter'`. If it cannot identify the file, the results of `print json_result.get(u'format')` will be `None`, and a new key titled `error` will exist in json_result.

Answer (score 0):

To know if it is an audio file, check the audio codec parsing the 'Stream #0:' field in ffmpeg output

If there is not Stream #0:0: or Stream #0:1: with the Audio field, your file is not audio. Stream #0:1 usually means it is a video file (video + audio).

Later, with this codec name, check if it is suitable for your system.

Example for a mp3 file:

```
ffmpeg -i yourfile 

.......

Duration: 00:05:01.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 203 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
```